Why can I send 1500-byte ICMPv6 frame but not 1500-byte UDP frame over mobile link?
I have a Purism Librem 5 phone running PureOS (a Debian-based Linux distro). I have an IPv6-only LTE connection. I started an SSH server on the phone and could connect to it from my PC. However, when trying to run vim or running commands with large outputs, the connection would hang. I suspected an MTU issue. The default MTU was set to 1500. And indeed, upon running tcpdump on the phone, I got ICMPv6 "Packet Too Big" with an MTU of 1460 when experimenting with different packet sizes.
With the MTU on the link still set to 1500, when I run:
$ ping -6 -c 1 -s 1452 example.com

I get a reply just fine without IPv6 fragmentation. (1452 bytes for the ICMPv6 payload, 8 for the ICMPv6 header and 40 for the IPv6 header. All of that should and does snugly fit inside a layer-2 frame with an MTU of 1500.) However, when I run:
$ head -c 1452 /dev/urandom | nc -6 -u example.com 80

(1452 bytes of payload in an 8-byte UDP segment inside a 40-byte IPv6 packet fits in a 1500 layer-2 MTU.) Surprisingly, I get an ICMPv6 "Packet Too Big" response from the first router. When executing the command a second time, I see that the network layer starts to send fragments which are dropped by an intermediary router or the endpoint, since I do not get a response.
The tcpdump dump:
IP6 2a02:a420:5a8:7995:b4a8:d2a:5dd8:63a2 > 2606:2800:21f:cb07:6820:80da:af6b:8b2c: ICMP6, echo request, id 23017, seq 1, length 1460
IP6 2606:2800:21f:cb07:6820:80da:af6b:8b2c > 2a02:a420:5a8:7995:b4a8:d2a:5dd8:63a2: ICMP6, echo reply, id 23017, seq 1, length 1460
IP6 2a02:a420:5a8:7995:b4a8:d2a:5dd8:63a2.54231 > 2606:2800:21f:cb07:6820:80da:af6b:8b2c.80: UDP, length 1452
IP6 2a02:a420:5a8:7995:e7f8:8337:fc2d:4700 > 2a02:a420:5a8:7995:b4a8:d2a:5dd8:63a2: ICMP6, packet too big, mtu 1460, length 1240
IP6 2a02:a420:5a8:7995:b4a8:d2a:5dd8:63a2 > 2606:2800:21f:cb07:6820:80da:af6b:8b2c: frag (0|1408) 39502 > 80: UDP, length 1452
IP6 2a02:a420:5a8:7995:b4a8:d2a:5dd8:63a2 > 2606:2800:21f:cb07:6820:80da:af6b:8b2c: frag (1408|52)

I understand that intermediary routers can do whatever they like with different kinds of traffic. But maybe there is something I'm missing and there is a reason why I can send an 1500-byte ICMPv6 frame, but I cannot send an 1500-byte UDP frame on this link?
Sending traffic to server I control
IP6 2a02:a420:278:b5a4:7920:8011:8740:42cb > 2001:41d0:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx: ICMP6, echo request, id 47837, seq 1, length 1460
IP6 2001:41d0:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx > 2a02:a420:278:b5a4:7920:8011:8740:42cb: ICMP6, echo reply, id 47837, seq 1, length 1460
IP6 2a02:a420:278:b5a4:7920:8011:8740:42cb > 2001:41d0:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx: frag (1408|52)
IP6 2a02:a420:278:b5a4:7920:8011:8740:42cb > 2001:41d0:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx: frag (0|1408) 57590 > 44000: UDP, length 1452
IP6 2001:41d0:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx > 2a02:a420:278:b5a4:7920:8011:8740:42cb: ICMP6, destination unreachable, unreachable port, 2001:41d0:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx udp port 44000, length 1240

This shows that both ICMPv6 echo requests and fragmented IPv6 packets do arrive at the target host.
UDP traceroute:
traceroute to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (2001:41d0:302:xxxx::xxxx), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  2001:41d0:aaaa:100::11  146.822 ms 2001:41d0:aaaa:100::5  34.088 ms 2001:41d0:aaaa:100::9  51.319 ms
 7  2001:41d0:aaaa:100::17  54.307 ms 2001:41d0:aaaa:100::11  42.921 ms 2001:41d0:aaaa:100::15  50.577 ms
 8  2001:41d0:aaaa:100::6  44.162 ms * 2001:41d0:aaaa:100::14  118.215 ms
 9  * 2001:41d0::43c  204.875 ms *
10  2001:41d0::437  124.893 ms  124.824 ms  124.762 ms
11  2001:41d0:0:50::5:285  124.691 ms 2001:41d0:0:50::5:bb  124.590 ms  132.521 ms
12  2001:41d0:0:50::1:8725  130.897 ms 2001:41d0:0:50::1:8945  131.201 ms 2001:41d0:0:50::1:8939  132.313 ms
13  2001:41d0:0:1:1:c38:2:0  130.811 ms  130.859 ms  130.864 ms
14  2001:41d0:302:c38::11  36.155 ms  41.817 ms  41.724 ms
15  * * *
16  2001:41d0:302:xxxx::xxxx  35.500 ms  35.377 ms  35.229 ms

ICMPv6 traceroute:
traceroute to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (2001:41d0:302:xxxx::xxxx), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  2001:67c:24f0:b000::102  135.569 ms  135.537 ms  135.515 ms
 5  * * *
 6  2001:41d0:aaaa:100::11  174.386 ms  40.346 ms  53.147 ms
 7  2001:41d0:aaaa:100::11  53.110 ms  52.418 ms  53.793 ms
 8  2001:41d0:aaaa:100::10  38.999 ms * *
 9  * * *
10  2001:41d0::42d  46.481 ms  46.579 ms  46.586 ms
11  2001:41d0:0:50::5:d5  46.583 ms  62.661 ms  62.634 ms
12  2001:41d0:0:50::1:8727  62.773 ms  63.762 ms  31.840 ms
13  2001:41d0:0:1:1:c38:2:0  31.725 ms  31.703 ms  31.683 ms
14  2001:41d0:302:c38::11  35.059 ms  35.042 ms  34.785 ms
15  * * *
16  * 2001:41d0:302:xxxx::xxxx  30.251 ms  30.044 ms


Does the remote side actually receive your ICMP Echo Request packets? (i.e. are the replies not spoofed?) Does the remote side receive your fragmented UDP packets? Does a traceroute with both ICMP and UDP modes show the same path both ways?

@grawity_u1686 I've added the information you requested. The remote server does receive the traffic and responds to it. The UDP traceroute shows similar, but not quite the same routes for every UDP packet.
